# Support multiple screens in Android

Tags: android

What are the various screen sizes in Android devices. I have three screen sizes which are 320X480, 420x00(Samsung Galaxy Player5.0), 600X1024(Samsung Galaxy Tab Sprint). How do I get my project/app in all devices with correctly fitted in all screen sizes.

Comment: check out my detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12742888/1369222

Answer (score 0):

here i am sending you an image for different screen sizes and densities.it will be help ful to you.[image: Device densities and sizes]