# Android Appropriate Image Resolution for ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, resolution

What is the proper/right resolution for Image to be put using src in ImageView to avoid stretching or unscaled images?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a single color of background, u can use 9Patch images. but if you are asking about icons then you need different images for different resolutions in drawable folders like `drawable-hdpi` for hdpi devices `drawable-xxhdpi` for xxhdpi devices.
for more details
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Comment: i am using it as a featured image. it takes most of the screen. My app only for tablet.  My problem is for landscape and portrait, the container or the ImageView changes its height and width

Comment: then use different images for both orientations .. or check if you can tweak with android:scaleType="---"  parameter of imageview according to your need..  Can you share your image or screen for more understanding.?

Comment: you got the point. also im already using it. but when i test it to 7 8 9 10 inches tablet. the images is ok in some screens but the other is stretch. I want the whole image to cover the whole container so i use android:scaleType="fit"

Comment: working in some screen sizes but when tested to other device with different screen size then the image is squeeze

Answer (score 0):

To understand the image size check out the following link      [image size (drawable-hdpi/ldpi/mdpi/xhdpi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381965/image-size-drawable-hdpi-ldpi-mdpi-xhdpi) . To avoid stretching use "android:scaleType="fitcenter/fitxy/centercrop""   for more detail check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually it totally depends on your placeholder or your needs, rather than single image you can make different sizes of image for different dp like small,large,normal,x-large .

probably https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio will save your time or new Android studio 2's built in plugin.

More resource
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html