# Android design for all screen size and resolution

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-drawable, android-relativelayout

Hi I am working on an app which has this [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM8iG.png). By using a lot of effort i developed [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTDau.png). But this is still not the same as given design and on other screens I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdNYA.png). This is the code in xml file. Any help willbe greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/dashboard_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@mipmap/logo" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@mipmap/logo" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Welcome text of app" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@mipmap/seperator" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@mipmap/regional_managers" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@mipmap/regions" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView3"
           android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@mipmap/graphs" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@mipmap/nationwide" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also tried links from so like 
[image size (drawable-hdpi/ldpi/mdpi/xhdpi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381965/image-size-drawable-hdpi-ldpi-mdpi-xhdpi)
and [Setting drawable folder to use for different resolutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079588/setting-drawable-folder-to-use-for-different-resolutions) but unable to get desired results. Any help willbe greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend you use a percent relative layout (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) to place things on the screen regardless of size. But a better option would be to embrace the Android paradigms, what about a nav drawer for your nav options, rather than floating buttons?

Comment: Had you tried putting the images in drawable- xxxhdpi/xxhdpi/hdpi/mdpi folders ?

Comment: @Francesc I would love to use android paradigms. but floating buttons are user requirements.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari yes I did as per standard

 ldpi | mdpi | tvdpi | hdpi | xhdpi | xxhdpi | xxxhdpi
    0.75 | 1    | 1.33  | 1.5  | 2     | 3      | 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="10%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="30%" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="20%"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="40%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="20%" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="60%"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="55%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="20%" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="30%"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="70%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="20%" />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I was not aware of percent relative layout. But after your comment, above answer and google docs I am able to get the desired results for all layouts except Nexus 9 and 10. Thanks for the help.