# android relationship between mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi how to calculate

Tags: android, android-image

android image size  different mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi ? i have a mdpi image 20*20 how to measure  hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi how to make other resolution image 
different screen sizes due to Android having set standard size ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [image size (drawable-hdpi/ldpi/mdpi/xhdpi)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381965/image-size-drawable-hdpi-ldpi-mdpi-xhdpi)

Answer (score 9):

Here is the scale factor list for each density:

- ldpi = 0.75x
- mdpi = 1.0x
- hdpi = 1.5x
- xhdpi = 2.0x
- xxhdpi = 3.0x
- xxxhdpi = 4.0x

So for example, if your mdpi image size is 20x20 then xhdpi size should be 40x40

Comment: how to measure formula calculate 20*15

Comment: imgWidth * scalefactor, imgHeight * scalefactor

-> 20(width),15(height) mdpi(1.0x) would result in 20x2=40(width), 15x2=30(height) xhdpi(2.0x)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following chart

```
mdpi                  20 * 20 pixels
hdpi   (mdpi * 1.5)   30 * 30 pixels
xhdpi  (mdpi * 2)     40 * 40 pixels
xxhdpi (mdpi * 3)     60 * 60 pixels
```

Comment: and how to calculate xxxdpi

Comment: if image 20*15 same rule apply

Comment: yes the same rule applies. for each length and width you have to separately multiply with the factor. so it will be 30 * 22 in hdpi, 40 * 30 in xhdpi