# Bubblewrap fails build. Unexpected error splash.png

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, bubblewrap

I am following [TWA Quick Start Guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/quick-start/). I am trying to build a **APK** using [bubblewrap](https:///www.npmjs.com/package/@bubblewrap/cli). I went through generating project files using **bubblewrap --init**.

The problem comes when I run **bubblewrap build**. I get a large [error log](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/rpxWgxJM5B/). I believe it fails to build my .png icons.

I tried using a different version of bubblewrap and changing .png size, nothing worked. I don't know what else I can try nor how to interpret error logs.

Comment: The error log on pastebin is returning a 404. If you have a link to a Web Manifest that points to those PNGs, I'm happy to try reproducing and check what's going on.

Comment: Thank you @andreban. I have found a solution and forgot to add a answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that **bubblewrap** was generating wrong image sizes. I manually edited [image sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381965/image-size-drawable-hdpi-ldpi-mdpi-xhdpi) in the **res** folder and the build went without errors.