# How can i made the layout that will work in both Tablet and phone?

Tags: android, layout, tablet

I made the layout from xml with on tablet layout of emulator size. But when open on same layout on android phone device then every thing distorted, So can i make a xml layout that will work fine in both of  device phone and tablet also. Please suggest me, appreciate your answer.

Comment: you will have to design your layouts and drawables for both screen sizes. check the docs has all the info you need http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I have given a detailed answer about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12742888/1369222

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078460/android-how-to-scale-a-layout-with-screen-size/19925666#19925666) answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make your resource like this.

**res/layout/my_layout.xml**                 // layout for normal screen size ("default")

**res/layout-small/my_layout.xml**            // layout for small screen size

**res/layout-large/my_layout.xml**       // layout for large screen size

**res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml**      // layout for extra large screen size

**res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml** // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

**res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png**        // bitmap for medium density

**res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png**        // bitmap for high density

**res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png**       // bitmap for extra high density

For more [reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). [reference1](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Handling-Multiple-Screen-Size-in-Android).

Add this in your manifest.xml

```
<supports-screens
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens= "true"
            android:anyDensity="true"
    />
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: image size will be same in all drawable folder? or will be putted the different size of image in each and every layout?

Comment: you should place different size of image. according to density.. because small images only fit for small screen . but it wont fit for larger screen because it looks very small. so we are moving like this. it's better to put different size of image.

Comment: @Nirmal Hi, I'm also used this but does not get solution. My device always shows normal layout only. I have added this permission  'android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout" ' This will affect anything.

Comment: what device are you using?

Comment: @Nirmal samsung note, and sony

Answer (score 6):

Make two separate layout for mobile or tablet just go your default layout design and click on **orientation for preview** and after click on **create tablet variation**. And after will see two layout for tab and mobile this is a easiest.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use Tables and weights to create the same or similar aspect ratio on a phone that would be on a tablet. I would only create different Layouts as a last resort.

```
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".33" >
             //Note: You will need some other TableRows fill in the difference of this Table Row..2 more of the same will equal 1.
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/x"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonx"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Words"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/x2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonx2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Other Words"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/x3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonx3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="More Words"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>
```

Comment: This is making what's inside your layout a percentage of the page. So whether it's on a TV Screen or the smallest device the aspect ratio is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two seperate layout for your phone and Tab. What you need to do is create a layout file with "filename" for phone and for tab create a layout file by right clicking project and selecting new>android xml layout file> and then type a "filename", click next and select Size from the right pane and select x-large from drop down list. Your layout file for tab is created separately so customise your layout seperately.