# Multiple screen support in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

In my app have six buttons,the screen size is 4.65" 720p(720X1280 : xhdpi),device take this resolution from normal layout folder.when i run it on device.it display like the image am shown below.how to set this six buttons fit to the screen according to layout width and height.I don't know the solution.Can any one know please help me to solve this issue.

**My XML coding**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/home_xml"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
    android:layout_width="101dp"
    android:layout_height="193dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
    android:background="@drawable/login_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_order"
    android:layout_width="101dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_login"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_login"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_login"
    android:background="@drawable/order_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_abtus"
    android:layout_width="101dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_order"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_order"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_order"
    android:background="@drawable/aboutus_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_outlet"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="198dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_login"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn_login"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_login"
    android:background="@drawable/outlets_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_feedback"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_outlet"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_order"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn_order"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_outlet"
    android:background="@drawable/feedback_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_games"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_feedback"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_abtus"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn_abtus"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_feedback"
    android:background="@drawable/games_button" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#98110e" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357682/how-can-i-made-the-layout-that-will-work-in-both-tablet-and-phone/17357736#17357736

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout_weight makes the button "share" the space.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some answers in this excellent official training : 
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html