# Android - dealing with different screen sizes

Tags: android

I suspect this is a well dealt with topic as I've read several posts as indicated below but I seem to be encountering screen size issues.

For example for the Asus FonePad using my calculation in the code below I calculate the screen size to be 6.833 inches but on researching further on the device it is advertised as a 7 inch device. This leads to me picking up the "wrong" screen size.

Below is the code indicating how I'm calculating the screen size of the devices using my app and subsequently calling the correct layout:

```
   // Splash screen delay
public final void SplashScreenThread() {

    //  For tracking purposes record in logcat SplashScreenThread() method has been called
    Log.i(TAG + "onCreate()", "SplashScreenThread(); HAS STARTED");

    // Thread for the display of the SplashScreen
    SplashThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while(_active && (waited < SplashTime)) {
                    sleep(100);
                    if(_active) {
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {

                // do nothing
                Log.e(TAG + "SplashScreenThread()", "SplashScreenThread() ERROR IS AS FOLLOWS: " + e.toString());
            } finally {
                    // Call method finish to kill any 
                    finish();

                    // Fetch the screen size in order to call correct layout wrt the next screen - firstly create and object of type DisplayMetrics
                    DisplayMetrics DeviceScreenSize = new DisplayMetrics();

                    // Secondly fetch the window manager using method chaining
                    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(DeviceScreenSize);

                    // Calculate the width of the screen in inches
                    double x_DeviceScreenSize = Math.pow(DeviceScreenSize.widthPixels/DeviceScreenSize.xdpi,2);

                    // Record in logcat DeviceScreenSize.xdpi
                    Log.d(TAG,"DeviceScreenSize.widthPixels is: " + DeviceScreenSize.widthPixels + " and DeviceScreenSize.xdpi is: " + DeviceScreenSize.xdpi);
                    Log.d(TAG,"DeviceScreenSize.heightPixels is: " + DeviceScreenSize.heightPixels + " and DeviceScreenSize.ydpi is: " + DeviceScreenSize.ydpi);

                    // Calculate the height of the screen in inches
                    double y_DeviceScreenSize = Math.pow(DeviceScreenSize.heightPixels/DeviceScreenSize.ydpi,2);

                    // Obtain screen size using pythagoras theorem
                    Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen = Math.sqrt(x_DeviceScreenSize + y_DeviceScreenSize);

                    // Record in logcat screen size in inches
                    Log.e(TAG,"DeviceScreenSize.widthPixels is: " + DeviceScreenSize.widthPixels + "\nDeviceScreenSize.heightPixels is: " + DeviceScreenSize.heightPixels + "\nScreen inches : " + Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen);

                    // Identify device screen size based on calculation of screen size
                    if (Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen < 2.9) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"< 2.9 inch range called");

                           Intent ScreenNotSupportedScreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, UnderDevlt_Scn_1_8inches.class);
                           startActivity(ScreenNotSupportedScreen);

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - DEVICE DETERMINED TO BE LESS THAN 2.9 INCHES - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen);
                    }  else if ((Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen >= 2.9) && (Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen < 3.6)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"2.9 to 3.6 inch range called");

                           Intent ScreenNotSupportedScreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, UnderDevlt_Scn_2_9inches.class);
                           startActivity(ScreenNotSupportedScreen);     

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen);                              
                    }  else if ((Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen >= 3.6) && (Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen < 3.8)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"3.6 to 3.8 inch range called");

                           Intent ScreenNotSupportedScreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, UnderDevlt_Scn_2_9inches.class);
                           startActivity(ScreenNotSupportedScreen); 

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen);
                    }  else if ((Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen >= 3.8) && (Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen < 4.0)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"3.8 to 4.0 inch range called"); 

                           Intent specific_login_screen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen_3_8inches.class);
                           startActivity(specific_login_screen);
                    }  else if ((Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen >= 4.0) && (Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen < 4.28)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"4.0 to 4.28 inch range called");

                           Intent specific_login_screen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen_4inches.class);
                           startActivity(specific_login_screen);

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen);
                    } else if ((Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen >= 4.28) && (Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen < 4.8)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"4.28 to 4.3 inch range called");

                           Intent specific_login_screen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen_4_28inches.class);
                           startActivity(specific_login_screen);

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen);
                    } else if ((Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen >= 4.8) && (Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen < 4.9)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"4.8 to 4.9 inch range called");

                           Intent specific_login_screen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen_4_65inches.class);
                           startActivity(specific_login_screen);

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen);
                    }  else if ((Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen >= 4.9) && (Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen < 5.5)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"4.9 to 5.5 inch range called");

                           Intent ScreenNotSupportedScreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen_4_98inches.class);
                           startActivity(ScreenNotSupportedScreen);

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen);
                    } else if ((Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen >= 5.5) && (Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen < 5.9)) {
                            Log.e(TAG,"5.5 to 5.9 inch range called");

                            Intent specific_login_screen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen_5_7inches.class);
                            startActivity(specific_login_screen);

                            Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen);
                    } else if ((Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen >= 5.9) && (Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen < 6.0)) {
                            Log.e(TAG,"5.9 to 6.0 inch range called");

                            Intent specific_login_screen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen_5_9inches.class);
                            startActivity(specific_login_screen);

                       Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen);
                    } else if ((Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen >= 6.0) && (Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen < 6.7)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"6.0 to 7.0 inch range called");

                           Intent ScreenNotSupportedScreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, UnderDevlt_Scn_Finish.class);
                           startActivity(ScreenNotSupportedScreen);

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen);
                    }  else if ((Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen >= 6.7) && (Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen < 8.0)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"7.0 to 8.0 inch range called");

                           Intent specific_login_screen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen.class);
                           startActivity(specific_login_screen);

                    }  else if ((Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen >= 8.0) && (Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen < 9.0)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"8.0 to 9.0 inch range called");

                           Intent ScreenNotSupportedScreen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, UnderDevlt_Scn_Finish.class);
                           startActivity(ScreenNotSupportedScreen);

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen);
                    } else if ((Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen >= 9.0) && (Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen <= 10.2)) {
                           Log.e(TAG,"> 9.0 to 10.2 inch range called");

                           Intent specific_login_screen = new Intent(SplashScreenFour.this, LogInScreen_10inches.class);
                           startActivity(specific_login_screen);

                           Log.e(TAG,"DEVICE NOT ACCOMODATED - ACTUAL DEVICE SIZE IS: " + Device_Screen_Size_In_Inches_To_Display_Log_In_Screen);
                    }
            }
        }
    };

    SplashThread.start();
}
```

As opposed to the above Is there any way to deal with the numerous array of devices?

Here's my manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="applcs.test"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="1.06">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:maxSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>

    <instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="applcs.test"
        android:label="AppLogInScreen_4inchesTestCase" />   

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />

    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
          android:normalScreens="true" 
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:xlargeScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_App_launcher_96"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />   

        <!-- Splash screen -->
        <activity   
            android:name="AppSplashScreenFour"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Login screens -->
        <activity android:name="AppLogInScreen_3_6_inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>     

        <activity android:name="AppLogInScreen_3_8inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppLogInScreen_4inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>        

        <activity android:name="AppLogInScreen_4_28inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>        

        <activity android:name="AppLogInScreen_4_65inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppLogInScreen_4_98inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppLogInScreen_5_7inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppLogInScreen_5_9inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>        

        <activity android:name="AppLogInScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>      

        <activity android:name="AppLogInScreen_10inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
        </activity>        

        <!-- Home screens -->       
        <activity android:name="AppHomeScreen_3_6inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppHomeScreen_3_8inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppHomeScreen_4inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>      

        <activity android:name="AppHomeScreen_4_28inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppHomeScreen_4_65inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppHomeScreen_4_98inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppHomeScreen_5_7inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppHomeScreen_5_9inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>        

        <activity android:name="AppHomeScreen_7inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>        

        <activity android:name="AppHomeScreen_10inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>     

        <!-- SW900 home screens -->
        <activity android:name="AppSW900AdminHomeScreen3_6inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

       <activity android:name="AppSW900AdminHomeScreen3_8inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
       </activity>          

       <activity android:name="AppSW900AdminHomeScreen4inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppSW900AdminHomeScreen4_28inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
        </activity>

       <activity android:name="AppSW900AdminHomeScreen4_65inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
       </activity>        

       <activity android:name="AppSW900AdminHomeScreen4_98inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
       </activity>        

       <activity android:name="AppSW900AdminHomeScreen5_7inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
       </activity>         

       <activity android:name="AppSW900AdminHomeScreen5_9inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
       </activity>        

       <activity android:name="AppSW900AdminHomeScreen7inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
       </activity>       

        <activity android:name="AppSW900AdminHomeScreen10inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <!-- Sales home screens -->       
        <activity android:name="AppSalesHomeScreen_4inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppSalesHomeScreen_7inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppSalesHomeScreen_10inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppProdBrochsHomeScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppSales_ProdBrochsScreen_4inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="AppSales_ProdBrochsScreen_7inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppSales_ProdBrochsScreen_10inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppSales_ProdVideosScreen_4inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppSales_ProdVideosScreen_7inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppSales_ProdVideosScreen_10inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppSales_ProdPricingScreen_7inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppVideoScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>        

        <activity android:name="AppPDFWebView"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity> 

        <activity android:name="AppPDFReader">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppVideoHomeScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppVideoHomeScreen2"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="AppListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name="AppVideoScreen_Tab0ProdCat1Prod1" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity> 

        <activity 
            android:name="AppVideoScreen_Tab0ProdCat1Prod2" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
        </activity>         

        <activity 
            android:name="AppVideoScreen_Tab0ProdCat1Prod3" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
        </activity> 

        <activity 
            android:name="AppVideoScreen_Tab0ProdCat1Prod4" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
        </activity> 

        <activity android:name="AndroidGridLayoutActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="FullImageActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="FullImageActivityTwo"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <!-- Under Devlt Scn -->
        <activity android:name="App_UnderDevlt_Scn"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>  

        <activity android:name="App_UnderDevlt_Scn_1_8inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="App_UnderDevlt_Scn_4inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>        

        <activity android:name="App_UnderDevlt_Scn_4_65inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>               

        <activity android:name="App_UnderDevlt_Scn_5_7inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>                     

        <activity android:name="App_UnderDevlt_Scn_7inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>                   

        <activity android:name="App_UnderDevlt_Scn_2_9inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>       

        <activity android:name="App_UnderDevlt_Scn_3_8inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>           

        <activity android:name="App_UnderDevlt_Scn_10inches"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>  

        <activity android:name="App_UnderDevlt_Scn_Finish"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>  

        <activity
            android:name="AppWebViewActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="SampleActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>  

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: But it is better way to make a folder in res folder for all support screens...so you get better solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17357736/1835764

Answer (score 0):

For Different screen size, The following is a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for small, medium, high, and extra high density screens.

```
 res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
 res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
 res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
 res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
 res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

 res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
 res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
 res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

The following code in the Manifest supports all dpis.

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: Hi Shani, thanks for the reply. I already added the <supports-screens > in my code from my early development and I've still been encountering screen size issues. Also I've got several layouts in res/layout folders.

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Hi Shani, thanks for the reply. I've posted the manifest above. Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html read this fully.