# Android support-screens

Tags: android, manifest, resolution, screens

How can I exclude the following "ldpi normal" screens from the Play Store?

WQVGA400 (240x400) 
WQVGA432 (240x432)

My app requires a minimum width of 320. This is in my manifest:

```
<supports-screens 
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

For Android 3.2+ there is an option android:requiresSmallestWidthDp, but I support 2.1 upwards, so this is not an option.

How can I do this?

Thanks,
Andrej

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357682/how-can-i-made-the-layout-that-will-work-in-both-tablet-and-phone/17357736#17357736

Answer (score 1):

i think the configurations you've mentioned should be inside the same category of small screens, so people with those screens shouldn't be able to install your app.

so i think your manifest is ok.

here's the description of small screens (taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#small)):

> android:smallScreens - Indicates whether the application supports
>   smaller screen form-factors. A small screen is defined as one with a
>   smaller aspect ratio than the "normal" (traditional HVGA) screen. An
>   application that does not support small screens will not be available
>   for small screen devices from external services (such as Google Play),
>   because there is little the platform can do to make such an
>   application work on a smaller screen. This is "true" by default.

Answer (score -1):

Also try adding `compatible-screen` tag in xml. Here is an example how you can do it:

```
<compatible-screens>

    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <!-- large screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <!-- xlarge screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Support screen only see the screen size but app design mainly uses `screen-density`. Tweak this part as per your requirement.

If you need more data about `compatible screen` search on developer docs.