# how to design different layouts login form Android for handset and tablet?

Tags: android, xml, layout

i want know , how to design different layouts login form Android for handset and tablet, like this image ...? thanks :)
[image]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Comment: I'd argue that the difference between those two images is not handset and tablet but simply portrait and landscape.

Answer (score 1):

Your best choice would be to go through these first

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

[How can i made the layout that will work in both Tablet and phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357682/how-can-i-made-the-layout-that-will-work-in-both-tablet-and-phone)